# React plugin to combine photos into an animated GIF

Tags: animation, gif, react

Is there any GIF plugin that combines a list of images and creates a gif.. That should be able to control the time each photo is shown and it should work across photo sizes and also compress the quality well..

Is there any plugin available for that requirement in react?